# Custom button in iOS with rounded rect stroke, icon and label

Tags: ios, button

[image: Button example]

I would like to recreate this button using code so it's a reusable object, and you can set the minimum width, height, or it stretches to fit the icon and label.  Throughout the app, we'll reuse the button in several areas and it will include a thin rounded rect stroke, a background color, an icon (trans PNG), and a label.  We want to make the background color, and stroke color configurable so we can toggle the button on/off.

[image: Example layout over a view area with background pattern]

---

EDIT: Almost working code but the text label block is white and need to resize image to fit in frame and both to be centered.

Custom button code:

```
#import "CustomButton.h"

@implementation CustomButton

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame image:(NSString *)image title:(NSString *)title background:(UIColor *)background border:(UIColor *)border 
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        self = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        CALayer *layer = [self layer];

        self.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentBottom;
        self.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;

        // background
        if (background) {
            layer.backgroundColor = (__bridge CGColorRef)(background);
        } else {
            layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor];
        }

        // border
        if (border) {
            layer.borderColor = (__bridge CGColorRef) (border);
        } else {
            layer.borderColor = [[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor];
        }
        layer.cornerRadius = 2.0f;
        layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;

        // icon
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:image]];
                                  [self addSubview:imageView];

        // text label
        UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 25, 55, 15)];
        titleLabel.font = [[UIFont alloc] fontWithSize:7.00];
                                titleLabel.text = title;
                                [self addSubview:titleLabel];

        [self setFrame:frame];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

---

EDIT: Updated code block above and got button to appear using the following code in the respective view in viewController:

```
CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(125, 3, 52, 37);
CustomButton *btnNearby = [[CustomButton alloc] initWithFrame:buttonFrame image:@"map.png" title:@"NEARBY" background:nil border:nil];
[myCustomView addSubview:btnNearby];
```

The custom button appears but still not formatted properly.

[image]

---

Here is an example icon (white PNG w/ trans) that should appear in center of button.

[image: Example map pin icon to appear in button]

---

Summary of desired functionality:

1) reusable button
 2) can have min width/height or override to match width of label and height of image + label
 3) has configurable stroke color
 4) matches button icon above with stroke + icon + label + background color
 5) can change the border color to toggle on/off

Comment: Updated my code block to show more of what I'm trying to accomplish with questions in comments.  See code above please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem and I'm sure it can be refined further but the button now appears as desired in question.  See snap of end result, and working code below hopefully to help others.

Working screenshot:
[image]

Working code:

CustomButton.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface CustomButton : UIButton
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame image:(NSString *)image title:(NSString *)title background:(UIColor *)background border:(UIColor *)border;
@end
```

CustomButton.m

```
#import "CustomButton.h"

@implementation CustomButton

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame image:(NSString *)image title:(NSString *)title background:(UIColor *)background border:(UIColor *)border 
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        self = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        CALayer *layer = [self layer];

        // background
        if (background) {
            layer.backgroundColor = (__bridge CGColorRef)(background);
        } else {
            layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor];
        }

        // border
        if (border) {
            layer.borderColor = (__bridge CGColorRef)(border);
        } else {
            layer.borderColor = [[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor];
        }
        layer.cornerRadius = 2.0f;
        layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;

        // icon
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(14,3,20,19)];
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:image];
        imageView.contentMode  = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        [self addSubview:imageView];

        // text label
        UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 50, 14)];
        titleLabel.opaque = NO;
        titleLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
        titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:7.00];
        titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        titleLabel.text = title;
        [self addSubview:titleLabel];

        [self setFrame:frame];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Instantiated the button on a UIImage layer that had segue to the View Controller:

```
// Add custom button to image view background layer
CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(125, 3, 50, 35);
CustomButton *btnNearby = [[CustomButton alloc] initWithFrame:buttonFrame image:@"map.png" title:@"NEARBY" background:nil border:nil];
[myCustomView addSubview:btnNearby];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation CustomButton

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andImageName:(NSString*)filename ofType:(NSString*)type
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) 
    {
        self = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        CALayer *layer = [self layer];
        layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
        layer.cornerRadius = 4.0f;
        layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;

        UIImage* img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:type]];
        UIImageView* imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
        [imgView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height)];
        [self addSubview:imgView];

        [self setFrame:frame];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)switchColor
{
    CALayer *layer = [self layer];

    if(buttonIsOn)
        layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
    else
        layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
}

@end
```

And everytime you use this button, just use:

`CustomButton* cusButton = [[CustomButton alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame];`

In order to alternate the stroke color, just call `switchColor` in the first line of `cusButton`'s target method and you should be fine.

Comment: when I want to initiated the button, could I instead declare the image during init like initWithImage:@"map.png" ?

and what is someFrame ?

and where do I add the label text below the icon?

Comment: also the isButtonOn is not declared anywhere.  is it perhaps better to just accept a color in switchColor and it sets to that color rather than fixed values?

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer to change the initializer to include an image name and type as well. I'm assuming you are using an image that's saved in the bundle. `someFrame` could be any frame - it's just an example I used there. It is meant to be the frame where you want the cusButton to be located. `isButtonOn` is a property you could add to the interface of `CustomButton` class. It can be of type `BOOL` and can be initialized as per your requirements.

Comment: See in the example image the text label below the image.  It appears your solution doesn't include the text label?  Also, I don't see a way to declare the button color, or stroke color, when instantiating the button.  Lastly, a way to set the size.  Given I may want a standard width/height for most, but in some instances I just let it set by the width of the label and height of the image + label.

Comment: I have given you a very good lead to go ahead from here. What you are asking here seems to be more of a direct answer than a helpful direction, so I advise you to follow the same concept I gave in my answer. Re-write the designated initializer and use some logic to where you want to get. It should not take more than 30 minutes! Thanks! I see that you have already used part of my answer to update your questions, so if you found the answer helpful, please accept it and upvote.

Comment: Ravi, updated the question so you wouldn't miss key elements of question.  Your solution failed to provide background, border, width, height, and text label which were all part of question.  I stubbed out what I'm trying to accomplish so if you can help complete that, I'd be happy to select answer.  As is, you missed 60% of question and we should not select answers that don't solve question for sake of people who view in future.

Comment: Added 1 upvote for some usable code and effort but didn't answer question.  I was able to build solution and will post working code that answers the question.

Comment: Mike, my code already provides a lead to set `borderColor`, `borderWidth`. Those are enough to get you a `border`. `background` is the `imgView` that we added in the code. All I didn't give you is the `textLabel` and I'm pretty sure you know where to get it from. Someone who doesn't even know where a `textLabel` sits in a UIButton wouldn't venture to create a sublcass of a UIButton. I'd definitely  say I gave you a complete skeleton to create a subclass that works 100%. What I definitely didn't give you is a subclass tailored to suit your requirements and Stackoverflow isn't a place for that.